# QuickFix/J - SessionID is null

Tags: java, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am trying to build a FIX engine to pull pricing data, based off of the Banzai class, however, I keep getting this error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "quickfix.SessionID.getBeginString()" because "sessionID" is null

I am able to logon perfectly fine, but not invoke the market data request, called in a GUI like so:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    userSymbol = enterSymbol.getText();
    System.out.println(userSymbol);

    try {
        System.out.println("Test" + sessionID);
        **QFIXApp.request44(userSymbol, sessionID);**
        System.out.println("Pass");
    } catch (SessionNotFound e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Fail");
    }
    
}
```

Here is my request44 method:

```
public static void request44(String userSymbol, SessionID sessionID) throws SessionNotFound{
    String request_ID = "EUR_USD_Request_";
    System.out.println(request_ID);
    //HashSet<SessionID> set = new HashSet<SessionID>();

    quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest request = new quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest();
    
    request.setField(new MDReqID(request_ID));
    request.set(new SubscriptionRequestType('1'));
    request.setField(new MarketDepth(0));
    request.setField(new NoRelatedSym(1));
    request.setField(new MDUpdateType(1));
    //set.add(sessionID);
    
    quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypes entry_types = new quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypes();
    entry_types.set(new MDEntryType());
    request.addGroup(entry_types);

    quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym symbols_group = new quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym();
    symbols_group.setField(new Symbol(userSymbol));
    request.addGroup(symbols_group);

    Session.sendToTarget(request, sessionID);
}
```

Here is my application implementation:

```
public void onCreate(SessionID sessionID) {
    System.out.println("Test" + sessionID);
    this.sessionID = sessionID;
    Session.lookupSession(sessionID).logon();
}

public void onLogon(SessionID sessionID) {
    observableLogon.logon(sessionID);
    sessionID2 = sessionID;
}

public void onLogout(SessionID sessionID) {
    observableLogon.logoff(sessionID);
}

public void onMessage( quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest message, SessionID sessionID ) throws FieldNotFound, UnsupportedMessageType, IncorrectTagValue { 
    System.out.println("On Message: " +message);
}

public void toAdmin(quickfix.Message message, SessionID sessionID) {
}

public void toApp(quickfix.Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws DoNotSend {
}

public void fromAdmin(quickfix.Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound,
IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, RejectLogon {
}

public void fromApp(quickfix.Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound,
IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType {
    crack(message, sessionID);
}

public class MessageProcessor implements Runnable {
    private quickfix.Message message;
    private SessionID sessionID;
```

I need to know why the sessionID in my GUI is returning null.
Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Where do you get the sessionID from in your gui class?

Comment: Here, at the beginning:
class QGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
 JFrame frame= new JFrame("FIX Quoting");

 JLabel symbol=new JLabel("Symbol: ");
 JButton subscribe=new JButton("Subscribe");
 JTextField enterSymbol=new JTextField("");
 String userSymbol;
 SessionID sessionID;

Comment: I mean where do you get its value from? From where is this initialized?

Comment: Is that similar to the 'LogonEvent' Class in Banzai? If so I realise I haven't got it initialised anywhere...I'm relatively new with programming so sorry about that

Comment: However I am using the LogOn Event class to logon, so the SessionID does initially work

Comment: So I guess you simply need to "hand over" the `SessionID` from your LogonEvent class to your piece of code above, i.e. your GUI class. Please read this: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj#creating-a-quickfixj-application You could then store the `SessionID` in your application's `onCreate` callback.

Comment: This is how my onCreate has been configured the whole time, however the sessionID never gets printed but 'test' does.

public void onCreate(SessionID sessionID) {
  System.out.println("Test" + sessionID);
  this.sessionID = sessionID;
  Session.lookupSession(sessionID).logon();
 }

Comment: Thank you for helping by the way! Really appreciate it, please let me know what you think is wrong with my onCreate :)

Comment: Could you share the code of your class that implements the `quickfix.Application` interface?

Comment: Just added it to my initial question, let me know if you need more :)

Comment: I solved the issue with :
SessionID sessionID = QLogonEvent.getSessionID();

Comment: Thanks for all your help Christoph!

Comment: No problem. I probably never would manage to find the problem in someone else's code I've never completely seen before. ;)